# Let $L$ be a regular language. Prove that $L_1$, the language created by removing all characters in odd places in all words of $L$, is regular

Tags: automata, regular-language

Let $L$ be a regular language. Prove that $L_1$, the language created by removing all characters in odd places in all words of $L$, is regular.

Completely stuck on this one. I tried  building DFA,NFA,$\epsilon$-NFA, product construction of automata, but I'm not sure how to even begin.

Comment: You mention you've tried building DFAs, NFAs, $\epsilon$-NFAs, etc. but can you say some more about _exactly_ what you've tried? Once we have a better idea of where you're struggling, we can help you better ^_^

Comment: I find that the [Myhill-Nerode Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myhill%E2%80%93Nerode_theorem) is helpful when none of these other tools seem to work.

Comment: You'll probably have more luck with this question on cs.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $L_1$ is the image of $L$ under the sequential automaton represented below, where $1$ is the empty word and $a$ is any letter of the alphabet.

$\hskip 60pt$
[image]

Since regular languages are closed under sequential automata, $L_1$ is regular.

Comment: What program did you use to draw your automaton? It's very nice.

Comment: @ShyPerson I use the $\LaTeX$ package gastex.